# How to restore a killed photoshop CS5 session on mac?

Tags: macos, mac, photoshop-cs5, session-restore

MBA with OSX 10.9.1

I was working late on Photoshop CS5 last night, and forgot to save my work. I put the computer to sleep and then went to sleep, but in the morning i needed to restart it to power it back up.

The programs reopened, but none of the unsaved sessions restored. Is there anyway of restoring these from Time Machine backups? Can i find temp photoshop files anywhere? I tried using StellarPhoenixMacDataRecovery and ran a data recovery, but couldnt find any files relating to photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though there is nothing I can do with this version.

> [left behind .tmp files] are temporary scratch files that can be safely discarded.  There is nothing useful you can do with them. [they store layer and history data but not a restorable version of the file itself].
>
> With Photoshop CS6 there may be auto-save recovery files as well nearby, but they're always .psb files, and you don't have to do anything special - Photoshop will automatically open them the next time you run it after a crash.  Photoshop CS5 did not have the auto-recovery feature; if it crashes you lose your work.

See [the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1064915) for more information

Comment: Can you summarize the most important stuff from the link here?